# Удаление столбца из таблицы

Tags: sql-server, sql

Как удалить столбец из таблицы SQL Server?

Answer (score 13):

> ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` DROP `COLUMN_NAME`
>   Не катит?...

Не хватает слова "COLUMN", запрос должен выглядеть так:

```sql
alter table 'table_name' drop column 'column_name'
```

Comment: Гм. А что оно это слово дает? Разве тут может быть неопределенность? Если надо уронить индекс, добавляем индекс, если всю колонку - просто название колонки.
Я не прав?

Необязательное слово COLUMN представляет собой ``белый шум'' и может быть опущено.
http://mysql.ru/docs/man/ALTER_TABLE.html
По крайней мере, если речь идет о Mysql

Comment: Если при удалении столбца не указать ключевое слово "column" то SQL Server решит что мы хотим удалить constraint. Автор вопроса спрашивал конкретно про SQL Server.

Answer (score 10):

```sql
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` DROP COLUMN `COLUMN_NAME`
```

Не катит?...

UPD: учтено замечание насчет ключевого слова COLUMN

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_query("alter table название_табл drop column название_столбца");
```

Comment: querty = query?...

Comment: mysql_query? 2016 год...